# Difference between using bquote() and expression(paste()) for labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So both lines of ggplot gets about the same graph, but which one is preferred? I normally see either one or another, but I couldn't find an explicit comparison between the two. Any light shined on this would be appreciated, thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars, aes(x=dist, y=speed))+geom_line()+labs(x='Distance travelled in m', y=expression(paste('Speed in' * m^2)))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x=dist, y=speed))+geom_line()+labs(x='Distance travelled in m', y=bquote('Speed in' * m^2))
```

[image: Using bquote]

edit: I realised I forgot a space after 'in' in ylab, ignore that mistake...

Answer (score 3):

```
expression('Speed in' ~ m^2)
```

`~` produces a space and different arguments to `paste` are separated by `,` (but `paste` is not needed here). See `help("plotmath")`.

`bquote` is a different beast. It let's you do this:

```
unit <- quote(m^2)
ggplot(cars, aes(x=dist, y=speed))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(x='Distance travelled in m', 
       y=bquote('Speed in' ~ .(unit)))
```